# Cassandra @Table enum type not found

Tags: cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

I am using spring data cassandra, and i have a @Table as defined below.

```
@Table(CassandraConstants.NotificationThread.NAME)
public class Event implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PrimaryKey
    private EventKey primaryKey;

    @Column(value = CassandraConstants.Event.COL_COMPONENT_TYPE)
    private ComponentType componentType;

...
}
```

In my dao code i am doing setting the enum value  and doing a save. but i get an error.

```
    event.setComponentType(ComponentType.CONNECTOR);

   ....

    this.eventDao.save(event);
```

but i see this error reported while doing the save action

Invalid value CONNECTOR of type unknown to the query builder...

Does the spring Data not handle the conversion of enums to string data type for cassandra ?

Any pointers to what is failing here.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the [official spring-data-cassandra project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-cassandra/), (repo at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra), that's under the Spring Data umbrella of projects, or a different project?

Comment: Does spring data cassandra support enum to string? I am using the official one only.